# промежуточное сохранение в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как сделать что бы canvas можно было сохранить, а потом заново отредатировать, как в фотошопе.
У меня есть библиотека 
https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor
тут пытаюсь реализовать http://333.novelsugar.com/index2.html
но не как не получается.
Вопрос такой написал пользователь на фото и произошло сохранение только не в png, а в canvas что бы это слово можно было заново отредактировать?

Comment: png можно нарисовать на канве и канву сохранить в png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а как отредактировать потом текстовое полк

Comment: я не смог понять это из вопроса, может быть сохранять текст и картинку в svg?